# Two fixed position divs develop margin when viewed on iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

Set up a website at www.fleetwoodlifecoaching.co.nz and everything looks great when viewed from a desktop computer, however when I view the website from my iPad an odd white space appears between two fixed position divs that make up the nav bar and heading areas (see screenshot).  They've been positioned pretty precisely and clearly the way iPad decodes this breaks it - what's the best way to get around this?

Thanks in advance for your help

Apparently I don't have enough reputation to post an image so here's an imgur link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrkGs.jpg

EDIT: So basically I have two divs that are right up against one another, one called nav that runs down the left side and another called header that runs along the top.  Below is the CSS for each:

```
#nav {
position: fixed;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-top: -17.5px;
padding-left: 40px;
width: 140px;
height: 100%;
background: #8E8074;
list-style: none;
z-index: 7;
}

#header {
position: fixed;
width: calc(100% + 16px);
height: 100px;
background-color: #8E8074;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-top: -120px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
z-index: 6;
}
```

Comment: Holler at us with some code that you have tried. But seriously, show us the code you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to make the margin on the bottom of the first block negative by a few pixels. If that pulls the second block up a bit that might cover up the white line. If that doesn't work than its clearly a coding problem and not that there actually is a gap or strip that is white in your design. Something to try maybe before you really dive into it.

Comment: Yeah the thing is this only happens on iPad, and changing the margin values would make it appear wrong everywhere else. Any ideas for a way that you can make something appear a certain way on iPads only? Perhaps a media query or similar? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The .5px is likely being rounded up to -17px by mobile safari leaving the 1px gap between the two divs, try changing the margin-top of the #nav to -18px instead of -17.5px.
The #nav style would then become:

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #8E8074;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 7;
}
```